# Numpy Zero Padding to match a certain shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file with arrays or different shapes. I want to zeropad all the array to match the largest shape. The largest shape is (93,13).

To test this I have the following code:

```
testarray = np.ones((41,13))
```

how can I zero pad this array to match the shape of (93,13)? And ultimately, how can I do it for thousands of rows?

Edit: The solution was found in the comments:

```
for index, array in enumerate(mfcc):
    testarray = np.zeros((93,13))
    for index,row in enumerate(array):
        for i in range(0,len(row)-1):
            testarray[index][i]= row[i]
            mfcc[index] = testarray
```

Comment: This could help you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297678/how-to-calculate-optimal-zero-padding-for-convolutional-neural-networks

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I don't see how this could help me. I'm just looking for a code to pad my array to match a shape.

Comment: One idea could be create the (93,13) matrix  and then fill it with the values of the (41,13) ..

Comment: For this particular assignment I'm not looking for a numpy answer. A for loop would suffice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this. `array` is your original array and in this case just for testcase. Just use your own one.

```
import numpy as np
array  = [[None] * 10]*10
#print(array)
testarray = np.zeros((93,13))
for index,row in enumerate(array):
    for i in range(0,len(row)-1):
        testarray[index][i]= row[i]
```

Comment: Thanks, this code does the job. How would I implement this in a For loop to iterate over an array with 50.000 arrays like this, and replace the rows with the newly created padded arrays?

Comment: Note that a for loop will perform much worse compared to numpy based solutions @TvCasteren

Answer (score 9):

Here's an approach using [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) that can generalize to an arbitrary target shape:

```
def to_shape(a, shape):
    y_, x_ = shape
    y, x = a.shape
    y_pad = (y_-y)
    x_pad = (x_-x)
    return np.pad(a,((y_pad//2, y_pad//2 + y_pad%2), 
                     (x_pad//2, x_pad//2 + x_pad%2)),
                  mode = 'constant')
```

---

For the proposed example:

```
a = np.ones((41,13))
shape = [93, 13]
to_shape(a, shape).shape
# (93, 13)
```

Lets check with another example:

```
shape = [100, 121]
to_shape(a, shape).shape
# (100, 121)
```

---

**Timings**

```
def florian(array, shape):
    #print(array)
    testarray = np.zeros(shape)
    for index,row in enumerate(array):
        for i in range(0,len(row)-1):
            testarray[index][i]= row[i]

def to_shape(a, shape):
    y_, x_ = shape
    y, x = a.shape
    y_pad = (y_-y)
    x_pad = (x_-x)
    return np.pad(a,((y_pad//2, y_pad//2 + y_pad%2), 
                     (x_pad//2, x_pad//2 + x_pad%2)),
                  mode = 'constant')

a = np.ones((500, 500))
shape = [1000, 1103]

%timeit florian(a, shape)
# 101 ms ± 5.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit to_shape(a, shape)
# 19.8 ms ± 318 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pad to the right and to the bottom of your original array in 2D, here's what you want:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((41,11))

desired_rows = 91
desired_cols = 13
b = np.pad(a, ((0, desired_rows-a.shape[0]), (0, desired_cols-a.shape[1])), 'constant', constant_values=0)
print(b)
"""
prints
[[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
"""
```

Of course it's not error-proof solution, e.g. if your desired number of rows or columns is smaller than corresponding size of the original array, you'll get `ValueError: index can't contain negative values`.

Answer (score 2):

To make the answer from @yatu a bit more generic. I wrote the following code

```
def to_shape(x, target_shape):
    padding_list = []
    for x_dim, target_dim in zip(x.shape, target_shape):
        pad_value = int(target_dim - x_dim)
        pad_tuple = ((pad_value//2, pad_value//2 + pad_value%2))
        padding_list.append(pad_tuple)
    
    return np.pad(x, tuple(padding_list), mode='constant')
```

Did not perform any timings but did a sanity check if it did what it needed to do. Note that this assume that the target shape is larger in ANY dimension compared to the input array x.

Comment: Adjust `pad_value = int(target_dim - x_dim)` to avoid `TypeError: `pad_width` must be of integral type.`

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution by creating zeros array and then filling in with slice notation.

```
def to_shape(a, shape):
    z = np.zeros(shape)
    z[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]] = a
    return z
```